# my_list.pop() does not remove the selected item from original list

Tags: ansible

I have to iterate through a list. I want to use my_var.pop to select the first item in my list. Do some stuff with the selected item and remove it from the original list.
I can select the first item properly, however, it's not removed.
What is the proper way in Ansible to iterate through a list. What do I miss?

Thanks!

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  vars:
    cluster_params: "1.1.1.1,2.2.2.2:5002;10.10.0.1|17,10.10.0.2|18,10.10.0.3|19,10.10.0.4|20\n3.3.3.3,4.4.4.4:5003;10.10.1.1|21,10.10.1.2|22,10.10.1.3|23,10.10.1.4|24"
    clusters: "{{ cluster_params.split('\n') }}"
    select_first_cluster: "{{ clusters.pop(0) }}"
#   Do some stuff on my selected cluster
    with_nested:
        - "{{ clusters }}" 

  tasks:
    - name: clusters
      debug:
        msg: 
          - "{{ clusters }}"
          - "The 'clusters' variable contains a {{ clusters | type_debug }}"

    - name: select_first_cluster
      debug:
        msg:  
          - "{{ select_first_cluster }}"
          - "The 'select_first_cluster' variable contains a {{ select_first_cluster | type_debug }}"

    - name: updated_clusters
      debug:
        msg: 
          - "{{ clusters }}"
          - "The 'clusters' variable contains a {{ clusters | type_debug }}"
```

Output:

```
PLAY [localhost] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [clusters] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        [
            "1.1.1.1,2.2.2.2:5002;10.10.0.1|17,10.10.0.2|18,10.10.0.3|19,10.10.0.4|20", 
            "3.3.3.3,4.4.4.4:5003;10.10.1.1|21,10.10.1.2|22,10.10.1.3|23,10.10.1.4|24"
        ], 
        "The 'clusters' variable contains a list"
    ]
}

TASK [select_first_cluster] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "1.1.1.1,2.2.2.2:5002;10.10.0.1|17,10.10.0.2|18,10.10.0.3|19,10.10.0.4|20", 
        "The 'select_first_cluster' variable contains a unicode"
    ]
}

TASK [updated_clusters] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        [
            "1.1.1.1,2.2.2.2:5002;10.10.0.1|17,10.10.0.2|18,10.10.0.3|19,10.10.0.4|20", 
            "3.3.3.3,4.4.4.4:5003;10.10.1.1|21,10.10.1.2|22,10.10.1.3|23,10.10.1.4|24"
        ], 
        "The 'clusters' variable contains a list"
    ]
}

TASK [separate_app1__from_app2] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        [
            "1.1.1.1,2.2.2.2:5002", 
            "10.10.0.1|17,10.10.0.2|18,10.10.0.3|19,10.10.0.4|20"
        ], 
        "The 'separate_app1__from_app2' variable contains a list"
    ]
}

TASK [separate_app1_ips__from_port] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        [
            "1.1.1.1,2.2.2.2", 
            "5002"
        ], 
        "The 'separate_app1_ips__from_port' variable contains a list"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=5    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   

(app-root) ansible-playbook loop_test.yml
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'

PLAY [localhost] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [clusters] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        [
            "1.1.1.1,2.2.2.2:5002;10.10.0.1|17,10.10.0.2|18,10.10.0.3|19,10.10.0.4|20", 
            "3.3.3.3,4.4.4.4:5003;10.10.1.1|21,10.10.1.2|22,10.10.1.3|23,10.10.1.4|24"
        ], 
        "The 'clusters' variable contains a list"
    ]
}

TASK [select_first_cluster] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "1.1.1.1,2.2.2.2:5002;10.10.0.1|17,10.10.0.2|18,10.10.0.3|19,10.10.0.4|20", 
        "The 'select_first_cluster' variable contains a unicode"
    ]
}

TASK [updated_clusters] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        [
            "1.1.1.1,2.2.2.2:5002;10.10.0.1|17,10.10.0.2|18,10.10.0.3|19,10.10.0.4|20", 
            "3.3.3.3,4.4.4.4:5003;10.10.1.1|21,10.10.1.2|22,10.10.1.3|23,10.10.1.4|24"
        ], 
        "The 'clusters' variable contains a list"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: @Frenchy check the debug message...

Comment: for downvote its not me...so i dont understant what you want..i see your original list but i odnt undesrtand what you want in your loop..could you explain the first loop for example, what yo uwant to display

Comment: @Frenchy, sorry if I wasn't clear. I think you are right. clusters is a list not a list of lists - my bad. However, pop in Python removes the returned value, and you can define the position of the value. Looks like in Ansible this is interpreted differently.

Comment: updated my original question to be more precise.

Comment: yes explain what you want from a start variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so i dont see where is your list of lists,

If you want to loop over clusters, you dont loop over vars but over task:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no    
  vars:
    cluster_params: "1.1.1.1,2.2.2.2:5002;10.10.0.1|17,10.10.0.2|18,10.10.0.3|19,10.10.0.4|20\n3.3.3.3,4.4.4.4:5003;10.10.1.1|21,10.10.1.2|22,10.10.1.3|23,10.10.1.4|24"
    clusters: "{{ cluster_params.split('\n') }}"

  tasks:
    - name: clusters
      debug:
        msg: 
          - "{{ item }}"
          - "The 'item' variable contains a {{ item | type_debug }}"
      loop: "{{clusters}}"
```